# Inductor dimensions as a function of time(?)

Tags: inductor, electromagnetism, toroid

While perusing the text book "Foundations of Analog and Digital Electronic Circuits" by Anant Agarwal , I came across this text in the section on inductors:

[image: inductor text]

Why are the dimensions of the inductor a function of time if the geometry of the inductor varies from the toroidal shape?

Comment: The larger the inductor the longer it takes for ALL of the inductor to magnetize when current is ON and longer to demagnetize when current is switched OFF. Thus the larger the core the lower the maximum frequency F is. The reciprocal of F is T, or time.

Comment: Yes....that is true...but the question is about the dimensions of the coil being time dependent as stated in the excerpt from the book....That is what I don't understand..

Comment: Well, the description is very bad, if not at all nonsense. If "the geometry of the inductor varies (with time?)", of course other things will vary (with time). I think the author is insulting the reader's intelligence.

Comment: Perhaps you can let us know the context of the comment in the book:
"Foundations of Analog and Digital Electronic Circuits - Anant Agarwal, J Lang, EE MIT": 
https://neurophysics.ucsd.edu/courses/physics_120/Agarwal%20and%20Lang%20(2005)%20Foundations%20of%20Analog%20and%20Digital.pdf. Cheers.

Comment: It never says "differs from the toroidal shape". It just says "varies" as in changes. Changes how? I don't know. The author never says. But if he means "changes with respect to time" then if the inductor's geometry  and shape can morph (like the T-1000), then its dimensions will also change, but this is super obvious and practically saying the same thing twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note that these dimensions will be functions of time if the geometry of the inductor varies.

The 'geometry' of a toroid could be thought of as a topology, and a few dimensions. The topology is the fact that it's a toroid, and the dimensions are the length and cross section of the ring.

If the geometry varies, then the dimensions vary, by definition. If they vary with time, then they vary with time. The author is stating a tautology (something that's automatically true by definition or by construction) that's unhelpful and confusing, at least in the case of the toroid, which tends not to vary its dimensions.

There **are** inductors that vary their dimensions with time.

One type of [pulse generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explosively_pumped_flux_compression_generator) sets up a magnetic field in an inductor, then uses explosives to rapidly compress the inductor into a smaller volume. These are single-use!

A [railgun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railgun) uses two parallel rails, with the projectile forming a shorting link between them. As the projectile moves along the rails, the loop area enclosed by the rail, projectile, return rail loop changes, and so does the inductance. One of the design parameters quoted for any given railgun design is the change in inductance per distance of projectile movement.

Comment: wow....I was totally confused by the text as written.  I kept trying to understand how dimensions on a coil were dependent on time when no mention is made that the geometry of the coil is varying with time.  Seems to me that the last statement in the text should read, " Note that these dimensions will be functions of time if the geometry of the inductor varies WITH TIME".  Thank you.